# What's the best way to do stuff when Nestjs application loads?

Tags: nestjs

When my Nest.js application loads, i need to run some database operations. (mainly around data initialization). All these tasks are already built and working as actions in controllers. If i go manually to /api/controller/action - they work. I need a way to call each one of them when the server loads up. Any advice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

NestJS exposes a few lifecycle hooks that you can implement in a service (or somewhere else for that matter). You simply create a service implementing the lifecycle hook you need and register it as a provider with your `AppModule`.

For instance:

```
@Injectable()
export class WarmupService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
    constructor(
        private readonly db: Db
    )

    onApplicationBootstrap() {
        this.db.doDataInitialization();
    }
}
```

You don't necessarily have to create a new service for this, you could also simply place this hook directly in your AppModule (or any other module for that matter).

You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events).

#### Before NestJS

If you instead need to run some logic *before* NestJS is initialized (and none of the lifecycle hooks above match), you can simply run it in the `main.ts` file before the call to `app.listen(..)`.